# Let the user create new elements in the frontend in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

### I want to create a ( + ) button that lets the user add new elements in the frontend of the application with its own Text and color.

[See the illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqhAY.png)

For [ studying + violin + Running + Movies ] are the create element using a pop up created with the (+) sign

---

basically an On Pressed function that lets me add an element, how do i write it, using what?

Comment: You need to explain more

Comment: Hello Ahmed, welcome to StackOverflow! Please ask more spesific question or add your current code so we can help. Also check this article, maybe that helps. https://medium.com/the-web-tub/making-a-todo-app-with-flutter-5c63dab88190

Comment: Edited the question for more clarification.

Comment: Thanks easeccy, it did help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate the user to another page. Take input on that page then navigate back. You can find navigation and routing examples in [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation).